# loop animation smoothly framer motion react for a list

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have a list of items that I want to animate across a screen.

```
const partners =[
{item: "Image"},
{item2: "Image"},
{item3: "Image"}
]



<motion.div
              // variants={marqueeVariants} animate="animate"
              //animate={{ x: 180, animationDuration:4 }}
              transition={{ from: 90, duration: 2, repeat: Infinity }}
              className=" h-36  bg-transparent w-3/4  px-32 overflow-x-scroll flex-row space-x-16 flex items-center justify-center "
            >
              {partners.map((partner) => {
                return (
                  <motion.div
                    key={partner.alt}
                    //  variants={marqueeVariants}
                    //  animate="animate"
                    className=" h-24 w-24 lg:32 lg:w-32 z-10 relative flex-shrink-0"
                  >
                    <Image
                      layout="fill"
                      className="h-full w-full object-cover grayscale"
                      alt={partner.alt}
                      src={partner.src}
                    />
                  </motion.div>
                );
              })}
            </motion.div>
```

I need them to be in constant motion moving from right to left. Only thing is when they reach the end there is a jerky animation before the animation loops again.
How can I fix this.
It would be even better if when one disappears to the left another is already appearing on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you figured this out but for anyone else learning framer-motion like myself, you need to set the easing value to linear.

```
transition={{ease: "linear", from: 90, duration: 2, repeat: Infinity }}
```

Reference the documentation for other values:
https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###ease